# How to multiply a layer by a constant vector element wise in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multiplication, weighted-average, ensemble-learning

I want to make a weighted average ensemble of 3 of my trained models. So, I want first to multiply the softmax output of a model (element-wise) by a vector and then average the 3 weighted outputs of the 3 models.

I used the following code to multiply the output of the first model by its weight vector:

```py
from keras.layers import Multiply, Average

resnet_weights = np.asarray([[0.91855, 0.99485, 0.89065, 0.96525, 0.98005,
                              0.93645, 0.6149, 0.934, 0.92505, 0.785, 0.85]], np.float32)
resnet_weight_tensor=tf.constant(resnet_weights, np.float32)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  
print(resnet_weight_tensor.eval())
sess.close()

resnet_weighted = Multiply()([finetuned_model.layers[-1].output, resnet_weight_tensor])
print(resnet_weighted)

new_model=Model(model.input, resnet_weighted)
```

However, I'm stuck with the following error:

[image: Error_message]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Lambda` instead of `Multiply`, and `K.constant` instead of `tf.constant` (is backend-neutral):

```py
resnet_weight_tensor=K.constant(resnet_weights, 'float32')
out = finetuned_model.layers[-1].output
resnet_weighted = Lambda(lambda x: x * resnet_weight_tensor)(out)
```

---

**FULL EXAMPLE**:

```py
## BUILD MODELS
batch_size  = 32
num_batches = 100
input_shape = (4,)
num_classes = 3

model_1 = make_model(input_shape,  8, num_classes)
model_2 = make_model(input_shape, 10, num_classes)
model_3 = make_model(input_shape, 12, num_classes)
```

```py
## BUILD ENSEMBLE
models = (model_1, model_2, model_3)
models_ins  = [model.input for model in models]
models_outs = [model.input for model in models]

outputs_weights = [np.random.random((batch_size, num_classes)),
                   np.random.random((batch_size, num_classes)),
                   np.random.random((batch_size, num_classes))]
outs_avg  = model_outputs_average(models, outputs_weights)

final_out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(outs_avg)
model_ensemble = Model(inputs=models_ins, outputs=final_out)
model_ensemble.compile('adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

```py
### TEST ENSEMBLE
x1 = np.random.randn(batch_size, *input_shape) # toy data
x2 = np.random.randn(batch_size, *input_shape)
x3 = np.random.randn(batch_size, *input_shape)
y  = np.random.randint(0,2,(batch_size, num_classes)) # toy labels

model_ensemble.fit([x1,x2,x3], y)
```

**Verify averaging**:

```py
[print(layer.name) for layer in model_ensemble.layers] # show layer names

preouts1    = get_layer_outputs(model_ensemble, 'lambda_1', [x1,x2,x3])
preouts2    = get_layer_outputs(model_ensemble, 'lambda_2', [x1,x2,x3])
preouts3    = get_layer_outputs(model_ensemble, 'lambda_3', [x1,x2,x3])
preouts_avg = get_layer_outputs(model_ensemble, 'average_1',[x1,x2,x3])

preouts = np.asarray([preouts1, preouts2, preouts3])
sum_of_diff_of_means = np.sum(np.mean(preouts, axis=0) - preouts_avg)
print(np.sum(np.mean([preouts1, preouts2, preouts3],axis=0) - preouts_avg))
# 4.69e-07
```

---

**Functions used**:

```py
def make_model(input_shape, dense_dim, num_classes=3):
    ipt = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x   = Dense(dense_dim,   activation='relu')(ipt)
    out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(ipt, out)
    model.compile('adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    return model

def model_outputs_average(models, outputs_weights):
    outs = [model.output for model in models]
    out_shape = K.int_shape(outs[0])[1:] # ignore batch dim

    assert all([(K.int_shape(out)[1:] == out_shape) for out in outs]), \
           "All model output shapes must match"

    outs_weights = [K.constant(w, 'float32') for w in outputs_weights]
    ow_shape = K.int_shape(outs_weights[0])
    assert all([(K.int_shape(w) == ow_shape) for w in outs_weights]), \
           "All outputs_weights and model.output shapes must match"

    weights_layers = [Lambda(lambda x: x * ow)(out) for ow, out 
                      in zip(outs_weights, outs)]

    return Average()(weights_layers)

def get_layer_outputs(model,layer_name,input_data,train_mode=False):
    outputs   = [layer.output for layer in model.layers if layer_name in layer.name]
    layers_fn = K.function([model.input, K.learning_phase()], outputs)
    return [layers_fn([input_data,int(train_mode)])][0][0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and detailed reply. when I tried to use the code that you suggested for averaging, I got the following error: ValueError: Layer concatenate_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.core.Lambda'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x0000021D2707D5C0>, <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x0000021D270124A8>, <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x0000021D2705C6A0>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Comment: ensemble_models = [weighted_resnet_model, weighted_xception_model, weighted_xception_model]
x_ensemble_out=keras.layers.Average()([model.output for model in ensemble_models])
print([model.name for model in ensemble_models])
print(x_ensemble_out.shape)

x_ensemble_softmax=Dense(11,activation='softmax')(x_ensemble_out)
weighted_average_ensemble_model =  Model(model_input, output=x_ensemble_softmax)

Comment: However, I feel there is something wrong. I think the dense layer makes a fully connected trainable layer from the Average layer to the output (with 132 parameters in this case). I just need the softmax output based on the averaging ensemble without making any training. I feel there is something that I still don't understand.

Comment: I mean, is there a way to use the average directly to decide about the model prediction (without a softmax)?

Comment: @MohamedHedeya Right, there was a chance it wouldn't work depending on your full code -- it'd help if you put the error messages in your question, and share your full model code via [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/). I'll look into it when I get the chance

Comment: Thanks a lot @OverLordGoldDragon. My full code is here: https://pastebin.com/1p8PJqQy. I look forward to having your advice. I don't want to train the weighted average ensemble (don't want to train a softmax layer). I just want to get the predictions using the weighted average results. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I found the answer to this. Instead of using a dense layer with softmax activation, I'll just add an activation layer (softmax) following the averaging layer.

Comment: @MohamedHedeya I'd advise against that - a learned softmax is likely to perform a lot better. The Dense also in part makes your tensor weights redundant, unless set directly to zero - as it learns weightings itself. Did you manage to combine it all into a single model?

Comment: Thanks for your advice @OverLordGoldDragon. I agree with you. However, as part of my research I want to compare the results of another ensemble to the pure weighted average ensemble. That's why I wanted to implement that weighted average ensemble without a trainable dense layer. Yes I managed to combine it all into a single model using the code that I sent above and on pastebin. Thank you very much for all your help. Also, I look forward to receiving comments from you on the averaging code that I sent. I want to make sure my code is correct, and has correct logic. Could you pls check and advse

Comment: @MohamedHedeya Unsure, as it wasn't exactly the _full_ model code (doesn't include pre-ensembles, and is missing several variable definitions) - but to verify, you should run `K.get_value()` on your inputs to `Average()`, and then on the outputs of `Average()`, and confirm the values are as expected. Since the problem appears solved, I'll just leave [this code](https://pastebin.com/VCnBm3Tn) I started to write for your reference.

Comment: @MohamedHedeya Finished it, out of interest - see updated. It uses Dense in output, but you can easily tweak it. If you found it and our discussions of help, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your time and help @OverLordGoldDragon . Should I then compile the individual weighted models, create an averaging model using Model(model.input, final_out), and compile the averaging model?

Comment: @MohamedHedeya Unless you plan on doing something specific with the individual models before you join them into an ensemble that requires compiling - no, you can just compile the final `Model` (which compiles everything at once).

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support @OverLordGoldDragon. The code snippent that you sent to me didn't work. It gave me AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'. The model code that worked with me is at the following link: https://pastebin.com/73tHV23W. I just cannot use K.get_value() to make sure that it correctly calculates the average of the model outputs. The error of K.get_value() is asking to feed values for the tensors. How can I get the values of the 3 base learner outputs as well as the output of Average? Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: @MohamedHedeya While I'm glad to help in resolving a problem in full, it's now expanding the scope of the question substantially beyond original; the code works for me, and can fail for you for a variety of reasons, including package versioning and runtime environment. You can open another question if you'd like, and mention me with '@' in a comment - I'll be better able to assist you there. The current question, however, is solved.

Comment: The need for this to be a Lambda layer is a very severe limitation of Keras. It means you can't easily package constant-valued layers into a model for exporting in other standard formats, for example porting the Keras model to Deep Learning 4 Java (because only standard layers are supported, not backend functions). It's hard to understand why a simple "ConstantTensorLayer" isn't supported, where you specify a tensor of any shape and set the values, and then it behaves like any other tensor in the graph.

Comment: A good example where this is needed is the MLNet saliency model, which has a component in some of the final layers to do element-wise multiplication by a constant tensor that defines a 2D prior distribution over an image region. MLNet defines it as a set of trainable parameters so it is represented as weights, but if someone wanted to hard code a pre-specified prior that is not trained, they can't. They'd have to make it a Lambda layer, instead of the much more natural idea of making it a "ConstantTensorLayer" and combining with a standard Multiply layer.

Comment: @ely Ditched TF/Keras for PyTorch recently - best decision ever.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is possibly caused by the mixture of kears api and tensorflow api, since your `resnet_weight_tensor` is a tensor from tensorflow api, while `finetuned_model.layers[-1].output` is the output from a keras layer. Some discusses can be seen here [issue 7362](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7362)

One walk around is to wrap `resnet_weight_tensor` into keras `Input` layer.

```py
from keras.layers import Multiply, Average, Input

resnet_weights = np.asarray([[0.91855, 0.99485, 0.89065, 0.96525, 0.98005,
                              0.93645, 0.6149, 0.934, 0.92505, 0.785, 0.85]], np.float32)
resnet_weight_tensor=tf.constant(resnet_weights, np.float32)
resnet_weight_input = Input(tensor=resnet_weight_tensor)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  
print(resnet_weight_tensor.eval())
sess.close()

resnet_weighted = Multiply()([finetuned_model.layers[-1].output, resnet_weight_input])
print(resnet_weighted)

new_model=Model([model.input, resnet_weight_input], resnet_weighted)
```